# Can you create a .dat file in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to write my first app for Android.  I knew Java formerly but it has been a year or two since I used it.

I want to create a simple file in internal storage - I understand I do not have to set any permissions to create such a file?

- Is it a .dat file I need if I want to save an ArrayList?  Does Android require me to use file extension when creating it?

Even with just trying the basic file creation - checking for existence of file and then creating it if it does not exist - does not work.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

(I have commented out the attempt to read the ArrayList, as I cannot even create the file.  Just trying the basic file creation.) 
(Also, I have tried the code with "Shares.dat" instead of just "Shares" as filename, that didn't work either.   I don't even know whether Android recognises .dat files and to be honest I am not 100% sure that is the file I need.)

(If by any chance anyone can help, I may not be able to test any solution until next weekend......)

As for the last but one line, originally it read 'context.getFileDir()' but my class extends ActionBarActivity and I found on internet a suggestion to change to this.getFileDir().  I got a null pointer warning when I used context.getFileDir()

```
 file = new File("Shares");

if (file.exists()){
    url.setText("File Exists");
    /*try{
    is = openFileInput("Shares");
    oi = new ObjectInputStream(is);
    details = (ArrayList<Action>)oi.readObject();//warning
    oi.close();//need finally??
    }
    catch(Exception e){url.setText((e.getMessage()));}
    url.setText(details.get(0).getAddresse());*/
}
else
{
try
{
            **file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "Shares");**

}
catch(Exception e){url.setText((e.getMessage()));}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a reference to a file that's created in private storage, you'd want to use [`getFileStreamPath("shares.dat")`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)) instead of creating a new `File` object.  File extension shouldn't matter, but it's a good practice to add a file extension to keep track for yourself what those files are for.

For example:

```
private boolean fileExists(Context _context, String _filename) {
    File temp = _context.getFileStreamPath(_filename);
    if(temp == null || !temp.exists()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then, if you wanted to write to a file named "shares.dat" then you'd use [`openFileOutput("shares.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)).  If you wanted to read in from that file, you'd use [`openFileInput("shares.dat")`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)).

```
// Read in from file
if(fileExists(this, "shares.dat")) {
    FileInputStream fis = this.openFileInput("shares.dat");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    ArrayList<Action> actions = (ArrayList<Action>)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
}

// Write out to file
FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("shares.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(actions);
oos.close();
```

All stream operations shown above have the ability to throw an `IOException`, so be sure to wrap that code in a try/catch block as needed.

Comment: thanks you very much for your answer mceley.  I modified my code thus:

Comment: file = this.getFileStreamPath("Shares.dat");
    if (file.exists()){
     url.setText("File Exists");
}
else    {
 url.setText("File does not exist");
   }

Comment: sorry, I am new to posting on here, or lack experience in doing so.  the above should be code.  I get message 'file does not exist'.  should that first line of code create the file in itself?

Comment: If you're getting "File does not exist" then the file doesn't exist. Make sure you're saving the file properly and not getting any exceptions in the saving code.

Comment: I can't really answer in any depth except at w/end but I did not want to appear rude by not answering.The code I posted of course runs at the outset of the app.Ideally I want the file to be created the first time a user presses a button and saves a 'Share' object.When I try this the app exits as soon as I press the button-I want any exception to be detailed in the 'url' text field but nothing appears but the message that the app is closing.I mentioned this is my first app, I think maybe I have to pare everything down and handle the button press event first and then figure how to create file.

Comment: Sorry for absence.First problem was I was using EditText to display error messages without using toString()-made my app exit immediately.Then I failed to initialise my ArrayList-I have not used Java for a while.When they were sorted out and I could get around to creating my .dat file and reading from it, your solution worked perfectly.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Better late than never.......I have not logged in here for a while, but I think I should probably have upvoted this answer as well as accepting it.  Apologies and thanks!